# Do I have to put inner parantheses when I compare two sets of expressions using the && operator?

Tags: java, operator-keyword

For this expression :

```
((a == b && b == c) && (a == b || b == c || a == c))
```

Is it legal to write it like below :

```
(a == b && b == c && a == b || b == c || a == c)
```

I want to compare the first set with the second set.

`a`, `b` and `c` are integers :

```
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;
```

Comment: It's always best to use parentheses to be sure. You don't get any advantages from leaving them out, but it increases readability by a huge margin. However the logic in the statement doesn't make much sense, the second part is completely irrelevant, as the first part expects that all variables are equal.

Comment: Maybe more importantly than asking "Is it legal" (which you can easily check with a compiler), you may want to ask "Is it equivalent?" which is a different question.  However, general principles say to write code that is more reflective of the underlying logic you want to convey, regardless of if some of the parentheses are redundant.

Comment: You got some answers already but for the future: why don't you try it yourself? Writing a test in some IDE would take about 5 min while writing this post probably took more than that.

Comment: @Amongalen While I agree in general, in this specific example one might mistakenly conclude they are equivalent.

Comment: thank you everyone for clarifying:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. `&&` is associative: `A && B && C` is the same as `A && (B && C)` and `(A && B) && C`, and `||` is as well: `A || B || C` is the same as `A || (B || C)` and `(A || B) || C`.

However, it does not work when two different operations are involved: `(A && B) || C` is very different from `A && (B || C)`. Furthermore, since `&&` binds more tightly than `||`, `A && B || C` is the same as the former, and different from the latter.

Thus, your first example

```
((a == b && b == c) && (a == b || b == c || a == c))
```

is equivalent to

```
(a == b && b == c && (a == b || b == c || a == c))
```

but your second example

```
(a == b && b == c && a == b || b == c || a == c)
```

is equivalent to a something completely different:

```
((a == b && b == c && a == b) || b == c || a == c)
```

(As Kayaman notes in the comments, it is irrelevant *in this particular example*, since all of them can be reduced to just `(a == b && b == c)`, by the virtue of specific predicates used in your example; thus, while they are identical *in this particular example*, you should still understand the concepts of associativity and precedence to be used in general.)

Answer (score 3):

It is legal, but it has a different meaning.

Since `&&` has higher priority than `||` and operators associate from left to right your second example is parsed as

```
((a == b && b == c) && a == b) || b == c || a == c
```

Answer (score 1):

AND (&&) operator has a higher precedence than OR (||) operator. This means that last comparison expressions:

- b == c
- a == c

will be computed after first half of your expression. After that OR operators will be calculated. So, yes **it is legal** in your case, but will return **different answer**.

Your condition will be computed as follows:

```
((a == b && b == c) && a == b) || b == c || a == c
```